# Django + Mezzanine + Github can't run project

Tags: python, django

I started a project on Django and saved it to Github. It's in a virtualenv. I then downloaded it from Github into another virtualenv, with the requirements met. When I try to

```
(virutalenv)Machine:project user$ python manage.py runserver
[snip snip]
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x10ad7cad0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
[snip snip]
  File "/Users/user/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/db/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    db = dbs[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
KeyError: 'default'
```

And when I try to load the settings in python, the following happens. The settings are in a file `settings.py` in the project root.

```
virtualenv)Machine:project user$ python                          
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 19 2013, 13:26:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.>>> from django.conf import settings as d_settings
>>> import settings as my_settings
>>> d_settings.configure(my_settings, DEBUG=True)
[snip snip]
  File "/Users/user/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 186, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.default_settings, name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LOGGING_CONFIG'
>>> import mezzanine.conf
Traceback (most recent call last):
[snip snip]
  File "/Users/user/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 186, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.default_settings, name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DATABASE_ROUTERS'
>>>
```

The whole, uncut transcript in this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/C8Cy6e6v.

The project runs fine on the original virtualenv. It complains about `ALLOWED_HOSTS` not being set, but that's never bothered it. The database setting is blank on the original, but that doesn't bother it either. I think the dev database is set somewhere in Mezzanine, but I'm not sure where. Mezzanine is using an sqlite3 database called `dev.db` in project root, but, once again, I could not figure out where that was set up. Forcing the database settings on the second virtualenv to read from a copy of the same database file has no effect.

I think it's just a question of loading the right settings, but I'm not sure where they are or where to find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. This command told me that the setting was in the default local_settings.

```
find ~/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/ -type f | while read this; do cat $this | grep 'dev\.db' && echo '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>' $this; done
        "NAME": "dev.db",
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> /Users/eeytan/dd2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine//project_template/local_settings.py.template
```

I then found out that the default `.gitignore` file has this file added by default.

This might have been obvious the person who downvoted me, but it took me a long time to figure out, because I was looking somewhere else for a solution. When you know where to look, it's obvious. This trend of downvoiting without explanation on StackOverflow is very disturbing.